# Как в sql 8.0 точно выбирать значения?

Tags: sql

Раньше если нужно выбрать позиции где слово входило целиком, то использовалось это

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column regexp '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]';
```

Сейчас выдается ошибка Illegal argument to a regular expression.
Какой теперь синтаксис?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sql 8.0 - это MySQL 8+, что ли?

[Regular Expression Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column regexp '\\b1\\b';
```